# Java + Android: Добавление группы View-элементов из XML-файла

Tags: java, android

Как с помощью метода добавить группу View-элементов из HTML-файла? 
Этой группой могут быть, например, контейнерный **Linear Layout** с текстовым заголовком, кнопками, картинкой и ещё чем угодно.

Зачем это нужно: если бы нужно было добавить, например, просто одну кнопку, то кода было бы очень мало, но если надо вставить составной объект (контейнер + содержимое с настроенным взаимным расположением), то тут наверняка рационально выносить добавляемый объект в XML-файл.

Чтобы не тратить много времени на ответ, не нужно писать полный пример с работающим java и xml-файлом, просто вставьте минимально необходимое количество строк в этот метод:

```
public void AddViewGroup(View viewGroup){
    // Добавляем содержимое, допустим, из groups.xml
}
```

Comment: В Java названия методов пишутся с маленькой буквы, а названия классов - с большой. Может вам это и кажется ерундой и вы такой особенный, что конвенция языка вам по барабану, но другие программисты будут думать про вас всякие гадости, пока вы не начнете соблюдать эту конвенцию.

Comment: Да нет, мне это не кажется ерундой, просто собирать информацию что с какой буквы писать можно до бесконечности и никогда не начать программировать. Но теперь, когда Вы сделали замечание, буду писать код в соответствии с этими правилами.

Comment: На самом деле [правил именования](https://comaqa.gitbooks.io/java-automation/content/rabota_s_failami/konventsiya_imenovaniya.html) совсем не много. [Полная конвенция](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), конечно, несколько объемнее, но собирать эту информацию не надо - она уже собрана в одном месте и разделена на главы и абзацы для лучшего восприятия.

Comment: Google имеет дополнительно [свои рекомендации](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) по оформлению кода для Android-разработчиков

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void AddViewGroup(View viewGroup){
    View group = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.groups, null);
    viewGroup.addView(group);
}
```

Comment: Все же не стоит поощрять "свободный" стиль товарищей, не уважающих соглашения и писать методы с большой буквы. Если человек не хочет следовать конвенции, то это он должен подстраиваться под правильное написание, а не вы под его

Comment: @pavlofff, согласен, просто скопипастил название метода из вопроса.